# 3 column responsive layout, right column below left column on mobile

Tags: css

I have this currently: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldyj5x14/7/

What I want it to do is have the right column go *below* the left column when the viewport width is less than 900px.

How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-left">Left</div>
    <div class="col-right">Right</div>
    <div class="col-center">Center</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 900px;
}

.col-left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.col-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
  background: lightblue;
}

.col-center {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  // put right column below the left column
}
```

Comment: something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/Ldyj5x14/3/ (center not floating here , notice it :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Close, but the right column should stay 200px and not span the whole width.

Comment: so clear it is :) https://jsfiddle.net/Ldyj5x14/9/

Answer (score 0):

you can just clear it but keep .center in the flow :

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
}

.col-left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.col-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  float: right;
  background: lightblue;
}

.col-center {
  /* width: 500px; */ /* optionnal */
  height: 600px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: gray;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .col-right {
    clear:left;
    float:left; /* maybe ? */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-left">Left</div>
    <div class="col-right">Right</div>
    <div class="col-center">Center</div>
</div>
```